# iPhone6 Display Zoom Functionality disturbs the whole view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, retina-display, iphone-6

I'm faces a problem with iPhone6' **Display Zooms** functionality, as on Xcode 6.1.1 simulator don't have Display Zoom functionality to test and its have standard display only.

**Problem:**

When I run my code on simulator and iPhone6 (with standard display) its work fine, but when I run my code on the iPhone6 (with Display Zoom functionality on) then my whole view disturbs from its original position and even UIButton are not even display or hide in this case.

Here are the two images of my scenario:

In the below image(iPhone 6 with standard display) all view is on its original position and everything is fine.

[image]

But in the following image (iPhone 6 with Display Zoom functionality is On) all things on view disturb from its original position and small ball(UIButton) around big ball are even hidden in this case.

[image]

Any help and suggestion will appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, display zoom just emulates the resolution of an iPhone 5/5S/5C. How does your app performs on these devices?

Comment: I didn't check on those devices, current i am facing this issue on the iphone 6 with display zoom on only any idea that how i fixed it or how i check this on xcode simulator is it the Apple's bug?

Comment: There is nothing to answer here. Make sure your ui behaves as expected on iPhone 5/5S simulators and it will behave the exact same way on iPhone 6 with Zoom Mode on.

Comment: yup the only issue I am facing is on iPhone6, so can we test zoom mode on simulator or something?

Comment: Irfan, I face the same issue in my app. It works as expected in the 'Standard Version'. But when in 'Zoomed' mode, the frames of the UIElements are disturbed. 

These links helped me in understanding the issue, 

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2014/09/use-display-zoom-iphone-6-plus.html

http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

But, how to handle it, am still figuring it out. Most probably need to check the nativeScale value, and update the frames accordingly! Just a thought!

Comment: Would be of great help if you let us know how you handled the Zoomed view of the app

Comment: Hello @coder284 check my answer below, hopefully it will also helps you in resolving that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a lot of searching and experiments, I was able to resolve this issue.

There are two things (I done with that specific View xib file) which help me out:

1) Uncheck the **Use Auto Layout** and **Use Size Classes**.

[image]

2) Not select any **Autoresizing** of that view which stretches in iPhone6' Display Zooms.

[image]

I hope this will also help other.

Thanks
Cheers!

Comment: Is that an alternative other than disabling Auto Layout (which is essential for different screen sizes for different devices) ?

Comment: Other way is to use Auto layout properly :)

Comment: Even with proper Auto Layout, the layout will probably be "broken" still, in Display Zoom mode.

Comment: Its still mystery then, the only solution comes in my mind is that we have to overcome this issue by implementing the screen design and continuously tests it on zoomed iOS device. If you find any other solution kindly do share here as an answer.

Comment: will do. Display Zoom will enlarge fonts & distort some buttons, when using Auto Layout.

Comment: @Irfan, Define "properly".