# Display zoom iOS 9 [resize]

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, standards

Is there a way to change frame of `UILabel` if the iPhone in Zoomed mode because the application is okay with standard mode but zoomed mode the `UILabel` inside `tableView` doesn't show whole text.

Comment: What do you mean by zoomed mode?

Comment: I think he means the "display zoom" mode of iPhones, e.g., see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395842/iphone6-display-zoom-functionality-disturbs-the-whole-view (iPhone 6+ "becomes" like an iPhone 6, iPhone 6 "becomes" like an iPhone 5)

Answer (score 3):

See [iPhone6 Display Zoom Functionality disturbs the whole view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395842/iphone6-display-zoom-functionality-disturbs-the-whole-view) for some ideas, but I wish there was a more comprehensive guide, e.g., from Apple, on how we can make our apps support "display zoom" properly. Any pointers to something like that? Anyone?