# iPhone6+ renders 736 points width on simulator but renders 667 points width on actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have used launch image with resolution 1242 * 2208 resolution.

So ideally the below macro should print 736 points irrespective of device,

```
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width), ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)))
```

But the width is returned to be 736 points on simulator and 667 points on an actual device.

What could be the issue?

Comment: It's because the zoom is on: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: I had a look at your link but could not figure out what is causing 667 width on device. I want it to be 736 just like the simulator. As far as i know, using appropriate launch image fixes the issue. What do you think is causing the issue?

Comment: It's the zoom: http://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-turn-on-off-display-zoom-on-iphone-6-6-plus/ It transforms a "iPhone 6+ screen" into a "iPhone 6 screen". Deactivate it.

Comment: Which is why you should almost never try to find out whether the phone is in iPhone 6+ or iPhone 6, because an iPhone 6+ with zoom behaves like an iPhone 6, and an iPhone 6 with zoom behaves like an iPhone 5. Exception: I downloaded an app displaying a ruler. That app needs to know _exactly_ what device you use.

Comment: Thanks @Larme. I was not aware of this setting.

Comment: @gnasher729 The weird part is that my UI works fine for iPhone6, but when I run it on iPhone 6+ with zoom ON, the UI is disturbed.

Comment: @gnasher729 Seems like display zoom can cause some issues to UI with AutoLayout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395842/iphone6-display-zoom-functionality-disturbs-the-whole-view

Comment: @Larme You can add it as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because *Zoom* is activated on your iPhone 6 Plus.
To activate/desactivate it: *Settings.app/Display & Brightness/Display Zoom/View*

As explained [here](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions), in terms of points (not in terms of pixel which needs to x3 for 6 Plus and x2 for 6):
Zoom Off iPhone 6Plus: 414 × 736
Zoom On  iPhone 6Plus: 375 × 667 (ie. like an iPhone 6)
Zoom Off iPhone 6    : 375 × 667
Zoom On  iPhone 6    : 320 × 568 (ie. like an iPhone 5+)